# MongoDB query with condition on multiple records

Tags: mongodb, database-design

This might be trivial, but I haven't figured out a way to do it.

Say I have the following records in the database:

```
{ A: 1, B: 2, C: "Red" }
{ A: 1, B: 2, C: "Blue"}
{ A: 1, B: 3, C: "Red" }
```

And I want to return all records with `{A: 1, C: "Red"}`, but not when `C: "Blue"` if there are multiple records with the same `B` values.  So for the above records, it'll only return the 3rd record.  The 1st record would not be returned because there are two records with the same B value, and one of them has `C: "Blue"` as a value.

I can only think of doing this via two queries to the database, i.e. first query {A:1, C:"Red"}, then check by querying all elements in database.  I suppose the second step might actually be many more than just 1 query.

I don't really want to query with `{A: 1}`.  Of course, I'm doing all this through the API, so this way it'll be one database query, but the resulting list could be much bigger than I'd like.

Is there a query that can do what I want via just 1 database call?  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think it's possible with one query. But you can get all B you want with [aggregate](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/aggregation/) and then query database for that B:

```
db.test1.aggregate(
    [
        {$group: {_id: "$B", count: {$sum:1}}},
        {$match: {count:1}}
    ]
)
```

will return you all B for which there only one record in your collection.

Comment: Ah I see, thanks.  I guess there are records with like `{C:white}` I need not to exclude so unfortunately it appears there might not be a one-query way to do it.